# Use of unresolved identifier 'LAContext' in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, touch-id

Apple claims to have this class in their arsenal [LAContext](https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication/lacontext#//apple_ref/occ/cl/LAContext), but Xcode 8.1 tells me otherwise: `Use of unresolved identifier 'LAContext'`

My line of code is as follows:

```
let context = LAContext()
```

To me this line of code doesn't seams to crazy ;), all the tutorial on-line make use of this no problem to check if TouchID is enabled, but in my Xcode, this is not the case.

What am I missing?

Comment: `import LocalAuthentication` missing!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to import the LocalAuthentication framework which contains this class and other related functionality.

```
import LocalAuthentication
```

Comment: Hmm.... how on earth I don't see that in any example. :/ Anyway, thank you for the quick response!

Comment: welcome, I don't see it in any of the examples either, I was trying to find a reference for you but couldn't :D